# return ID's of unique combinations

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My data table has the following format

```
ID   Var1   Var2   Var3   ...
1_1  0      0      1      ...
1_2  1      1      0      ...
1_3  0      0      1      ...
...  ...    ...    ...    ...
```

I want to extract the ID's from unique combinations (`Var`columns). Getting the unique combinations is not the problem (`plyr::count()`, `aggregate()` etc), I want to extract the `id` variables contributing to these unique combinations.

The output should look somewhat like this

```
Var1   Var2   Var3   IDs
0      0      1      1_1, 1_3
1      1      0      1_2
```

where the `IDs` column is a vector/list of all the ID's contributing to a unique combination.

I tried an [R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/crs/versions/0.15-31/topics/uniquecombs) and `dplyr` pipelines, nothing worked so far.

Any suggestions or even R packages how to handle this task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df %>% group_by_at(.vars=-1) %>% summarize(IDs=list(ID))
```

Similar to Sotos' solution, but simplifies selection of the ID column assuming all other columns need to be unique, and IDs column will be a column of lists rather than a string.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Var1, Var2 [2]
   Var1  Var2  Var3 IDs      
  <int> <int> <int> <list>   
1     0     0     1 <chr [2]>
2     1     1     0 <chr [1]>
```

---

Just for fun, you can further simplify it using `tidyr`'s `nest` function:

```
require(tidyr)
nest(df,IDs=ID)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
   Var1  Var2  Var3 IDs                
  <int> <int> <int> <S3: vctrs_list_of>
1     0     0     1 1_1, 1_3           
2     1     1     0 1_2
```

This still leaves IDs as a list, which may or may not be useful for you, but displays it more clearly in the tibble. An extra benefit of keeping the column as a list rather than a string is that you can easily recreate the original table using `unnest`:

```
unnest(nest(dd,IDs=ID),cols=IDs)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   Var1  Var2  Var3 ID   
  <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1     0     0     1 1_1  
2     0     0     1 1_3  
3     1     1     0 1_2
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `group_by_at` with the pattern that matches your column names, and summarise, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 group_by_at(vars(contains('Var'))) %>% 
 summarise(IDs = toString(ID))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 4
> # Groups:   Var1, Var2 [2]
>    Var1  Var2  Var3 IDs     
>   <int> <int> <int> <chr>   
> 1     0     0     1 1_1, 1_3
> 2     1     1     0 1_2
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach worked perfectly fine. Ultimately, I used a combination of your and @iod answer. ```df = df %>% 
  group_by_at(.vars=-1) %>% 
  summarize(IDs=toString(ID))```

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregate and unique

```
aggregate(dat$ID,list(dat$Var1,dat$Var2,dat$Var3),unique)
```